# Laravel 8 - Process millions of records in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, queue, job-scheduling

There are millions of records in a database table.

**purchase**

```
id (increments), device_id (int), app_id (int), status(boolean), receipt (string)
```

My framework laravel 8 and I use mysql

I have created a command

**app/Console/Commands/ProcessPurchase.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\Purchase;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use App\Jobs\ProcessPurchaseJob;

class ProcessPurchase extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'process:purchase';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function handle()
{
    Log::info('process:purchase command start successfully.');
    $purchases = Purchase::getUnequalizedPurchases(250);
    if(count($purchases) > 0) {
        foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
            //push job to the queue
            Queue::push((new ProcessPurchaseJob($purchase, $purchase->os)));
        }
    } else {
        Log::info('process:purchase command end successfully.');
    }
}
}
```

and created a job

**app/Console/Commands/ProcessPurchaseJob.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Purchase;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ProcessPurchaseJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

private $purchase, $os;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Purchase $purchase, string $os)
{
    $this->purchase = $purchase;
    $this->os = $os;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    //getting data from the third-party endpoint
    if($purchaseData = getPurchaseDataFromMarket($this->purchase->receipt, $this->os)) {
        $this->purchase->expire_date = $purchaseData['expire_date'];
        $this->purchase->status = $purchaseData['status'];
        try {
            $this->purchase->save();
            Log::info('purchase job runned successfully. receipt : ' . $this->purchase->receipt);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            Log::error($exception->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        Log::error('purchase request error. receipt : ' . $this->purchase->receipt);
    }
}
}
```

and added to **app/http/Console/Kernel.php**

```
$schedule->command('process:purchase')
        ->everyFiveMinutes();
```

to start cron, execute this command.

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan schedule:work
```

to do the jobs in queue, execute this command

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

I should send a request to third-party HTTP endpoint and update per every record.

This process take 1.5 secs about per a record. So, for 10.000.000 records, it takes 173.6 days.
I should can process all these data in a short time. (like 12 hours etc.)

What should i do ?

Comment: How about process purchase queue job in moment purchase has been made?

Comment: I need to update record which expire_date is passed and status=true.

Comment: If you have to send 10.000.000 records to the api, and the api takes 1.5s per record, then it will take that time. My main concerns would be: a) do you actually need to send all those records to the api (and every time? why? that logic is probably hidden in "getUnequalizedPurchases", which you didnt share) b) does the api have a batch processing alternative where you can send multiple records at the same time that might be faster and/or is there a different function that maybe return records to update. Both things we cannot answer for you, but will probably decide your execution time.

Comment: I should send request and update it on database with response per every record which are status=true and expire_date is passed on every day.

Response example {"status":"false", "expire_date": "2020-01-01"}

Comment: I am not sure you understood my comment. You said that you have to update 10.000.000 records. For each, you have to send a request to an api, that takes 1.5s per record. These are the information you gave us, and if correct, yes, it will take 10mill*1.5s. If that infomation is not correct, you probably have 2 ways to go: reduce the number of 10kk record to process (which I'd guess is the right way to go) or find a faster api function. To advise you further, you'd need to provide more information (e.g. about your application logic and/or at least the getUnequalizedPurchases-code).